# Multiple vectorized condition - Length of values between two data frames not matching

Tags: pandas, numpy

I am trying to perform a rather simple task by using vectorized conditions. The size of the two dataframes differ but still I do not understand why that may an issue.

```
df1_data = {'In-Person Status': {0: 'No', 1: 'Yes', 2: 'No', 3: 'Yes', 4: 'No', 5: 'Yes'},
 'ID': {0: 5, 1: 45, 2: 22, 3: 34, 4: 46, 5: 184}}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1_data)      

df2_data = {'Age': {0: 22, 1: 34, 2: 51, 3: 8}, 'ID': {0: 5, 1: 2145, 2: 5022, 3: 34}}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2_data)
```

I am using the following code:

```
conditions = [
    (df2['ID'].isin(df1['ID'])) & (df1['In-Person Status'] == 'No')
]
    
value = ['True']

df2['Result'] = NaN
df2['Result'] = np.select(conditions, value, 'False')
```

Desired output:

```
 Age             ID       Result 
 22             0005       True
 34             2145       False
 51             5022       False
 8              0034       False
```

Although the task might be very simple, I am getting the following error message:
ValueError: Length of values (72610) does not match length of index (1634)

I would very much appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: If you want to reference the other table, try merging the table and apply the logical operation.

Comment: merge the two dataframes together using how='left' then do your combined conditions on the merged dataframe.

Comment: Right the second that I posted it I thought to myself, "omg how you haven't thought about it from the beginning" thanks though. I was wondering if in general my initial question could be solved without the most logical thing which was the merge. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: `isin` is possible but assigning the result of `==` of other table with different shape is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can join the two dfs as suggested in the comments, then drop the nan value rows in the Age column. The last couple of lines are optional to get the format to match your output.

```
dfj = df1.join(df2, rsuffix='_left')

conditions = [(dfj['ID'].isin(dfj['ID_left'])) & (dfj['In-Person Status'] == 'No')]
    
value = [True]
dfj['Result'] = np.select(conditions, value, False)

dfj = dfj.dropna(axis=0, how='any', subset=['Age'])

dfj = dfj[['Age' , 'ID_left', 'Result']]

dfj.columns = ['Age', 'ID', 'Result']

dfj['ID'] = dfj['ID'].apply(lambda x: str(x).zfill(6)[0:4])

dfj['Age'] = dfj['Age'].astype(int)
```

Output:

```
    Age ID      Result
0   22  0005    True
1   34  2145    False
2   51  5022    False
3   8   0034    False
```